# Proving $\min\{x^4+x y+y^2-6 x-5 y\}=-9$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I first found that

$$\min\{x^4+x y+y^2-6 x-5 y\} = -9$$

by knowing that if a point is a critical point, then the first partial derivatives with respect to $x$ and $y$ must be zero. Then I found the points that satisfies this constraint, which are just $(1,2)$. Then simply $f(1,2) = -9$. But critical point isn't necessarly minimum or maximum, so I have to prove that:

$$f(x,y)\ge f(x_0,y_0) = -9$$

for all $(x,y)$.

So basically I'm trying to prove that:

$$f(x,y)-f(x_0,y_0)\ge 0$$

We have that:

$$f(x,y)-f(x_0,y_0) = x^4+x y+y^2-6 x-5 y+9$$

Since I want to prove that this difference is greater than or equal to $0$ I tried to arrange everything in squares but it didn't end up very well. Any ideas to prove

$$f(x,y)-f(x_0,y_0) = x^4+x y+y^2-6 x-5 y+9>0 \text{ ?}$$

ps: just don't throw another method of proving that this is indeed a minimum point, I know other ways, but I wanted to do it this way for knowledge.

Comment: should not it be $x^4 +xy + y^2 -6x -5y + 9$ ?. I think about this: i will try to complete the squares for example i will add $x^2 $ , multiply with 2 $2x^4 +2xy +2y^2 -12x - 10 y + 18 > 0$ add $x^2$ , $2x^4 -x^2 +x^2 + 2xy + y^2 + y^2 - 12 x - 10 y + 18 = 2x^4 -x^2 + (x+y)^2+ (y-5)^2 - 7$. now i will study if $2x^4 - x^2 - 7 > 0$

Comment: @Ameryr yes thanks

Comment: I edited my post

Comment: @Ameryr isn't it enough to study just $-x^2-7$?

Comment: no since this will always be negative and we will fail. I think also this $2x^4 -x^2 -7 >0$ is not true for all $x$ so I will think about adding of the terms I ignored

Comment: Re: *critical point isn't necessarly minimum or maximum*. But if you can say how the function behaves for large values, knowing critical points could be enough information. Since we know that a continuous function attains minimum/maximum on every compact set. So if you restrict to $(x,y)\in[-N,N]\times[-N,N]$, then you know that min/max will be either at a critical point or on the boundary. So if you can somehow show that for large enough $N$ all values on boundary are $>-9$, your done. (And you can choose circle instead of square, if it makes things easier.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hint:

$P(y)=y^2+(x-5)y+x^4-6x=(y+\dfrac{x-5}{2})^2+x^4-(\dfrac{x-5}{2})^2-6x$
$Q(x)=x^4-(\dfrac{x-5}{2})^2-6x$

find $Q_{min}$, then you can find $P_{min}=Q_{min}$ when $y+\dfrac{x-5}{2}=0$